# How To Add Monotouch Dialog to FlyoutNaviagtionController

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm a noob to monotouch and can't manage to add table views to flyoutnavigation controller.  Does anyone have an example?

** update

My setup is a bit complicated and after much hacking managed to get the static table cells displayed on my storyboard with the below config.

```
tab bar controller
|
-tab 1
|
-tab 2 - nav controller
         |
         uiview controller A -  flyout nav A --> uiview controller A1...A3
         |
         uiview controller B -  flyout nav B --> tableview controller B1 (static cells)
```

I've cast the tableview controllers as uiview controllers on the flyout navs' setup thus allowing the tableviewcontroller to be displayed correctly and navigated to main uiview controllers via sergues.  For example in the flyouts setup:

```
NavigationRoot = new RootElement ("FlyoutNavigationB") {
    new Section ("Pages") {
        new StringElement ("A Table View with static cells")
    }
},


ViewControllers = new [] {
  TableViewControllerB1 as UIViewController,
},
```

This hack seems to work but cleaner solutions are warmly invited (as I'm only 2weeks dev experience with monotouch) and feel a little saddened that I have uiview controllers sitting unattached on the storyboard without ability to do sergues via the flyout nav. It almost behaves like old school xib development.

Anyway I'm experimenting with tying this upto monotouch dialog now but not yet sure how.  Comments most welcome to aid my learning :P

*** update

Ok I think I got it working by creating a subclassed dialogviewcontroller.  Then passing this subclass instance into the ViewControllers array in flyoutnavigationcontroller like so:

```
public partial class MyDvcController : DialogViewController
{
    public MyDvcController (UINavigationController nav): base (UITableViewStyle.Grouped, null)
    {

        navigation = nav;
        Root = new RootElement ("Demos"){
            new Section ("Element API"){
                new StringElement ("iPhone Settings Sample", DemoElementApi),

            }
        };
    }
}
```

In my calling flyoutnav controller:

```
// Supply view controllers corresponding to menu items:
            ViewControllers = new [] {
                new UIViewController { View = new UILabel { Text = "Address txt" }, Title = "Address" },
                new MyDvcController(NavigationController) as UIViewController                                                                                                    
            }
```

My wish list is almost complete...now how to add custom upickerviews with lovely transparent input accessory views wired to inputviews so they show automatically from calling monotouch dialog elements...hmmmm...another quest awaits...

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to push a second list over inside the flyout? I couldn't get it to work either.

I got it to work by modifying [the source](https://github.com/Clancey/FlyoutNavigation) and redoing how the selection list is setup--but those changes are on my machine at work. I'll try to push those when I have a chance.

Comment: yes i was...just updated my original question with something i managed to get working without tampering with source.

Comment: Were any of you able to work with second list? can you share some code if you got it to work?

Comment: @jonathanpeppers. How can i change the background color of side menu using FlyoutNavigation? All samples avoid to try this and remaining white backgound!

Comment: The flyout menu is a `UITableView` all you have to do is change its background color like you would normally.